# How to calibrate my screen on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, color-management, monitor-calibration

None of the available color profiles for my monitor (Samsung SMB1630N) work properly and I cannot find any option to calibrate it myself. 
I searched for an updated version of GNOME Color Manager but there is not one for the Ubuntu 16.04.